# How can I repair a totally corrupt rpm db on centos 6.4 with no backup?

Tags: linux, backup, repair, centos-6

I am looking for help in repairing my Centos 6.4 rpm db. I had a disk failure and the backup rpm i have is not working also.

I have googled the request and have come up with many different solutions but none really apply to my issue, as I have no rpm db to start with and need to rebuild from what is currently installed.

Is there a way I can pretend to install the packages its telling me I have missing without actually installing them, so I can repair my rpm db...?

Any assistance will be greatful.
(Many thanks to all in advance)

Comment: Why not just reinstall packages you're missing? Should the packages be well defined, they will not overwrite configuration files and thus you'll end up with a fully working system, rpmdb and all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want/need to reconstruct /var/lib/rpm
after a disk crash, so I will answer that question.

Look for /var/log/rpmpkgs. That is a cron driven
list of the packages in the rpmdb. The existence
of the file depends on whether you installed rpm-cron
however.

If you have the list of pkgs that were installed, then
download, and reinstall.

If you don't have the list of packages, and /var/lib/rpm/Packages
doesn/t exist, the easiest fix is to grab a copy of /var/lib/rpm/Packages
from some similar machine, and put in place. Do "rpm --rebuilddb" to
regenerate the indices. Finally, do "rpm -Va" paying attention to the
output. Missing files are an indication that the package was not
installed, modified files are an indication that you had a different
version.

You can install with --justdb to just register the package header. In
practice its usually just as easy to reinstall the entire package, including
content, to recreate an rpmdb.